# c++ left mouse button down help

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, winapi

ok i know how to do the left mouse button down evet(WM_LBUTTONDOWN). but im having some troubles with it. when use it with vectors it seems to add 101 elemnts everytime the left mouse button is down. i think that every time the mouse button is down, it sends 101 messages to WM_LBUTTONDOWN that causes 101 elements to be added.
here is the code for the event

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    iRegularShots=0;
    pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
    pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam); 
    pRegularShots.push_back(pt); 
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false); 
    break;
```

any ideas ?

---

im not missing a break;
i used teh size() function to tell me how many elemnts were assigned.
i set two break points one one pRegularShots.push_back(pt); and the other one on different function that will use what is inside the vector to display the image. and i got 101 calls over there but only one call on the pRegularShots.push_back(pt);.
this is the function code

```
VOID fRegularShot(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd) 
{ 
    Graphics graphics(hdc); 
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png"); 
    long index=0;
    long s=pRegularShots.size();
    while(index < (long)pRegularShots.size()) 
    { 
        graphics.DrawImage(&shot, pRegularShots[index].x, pRegularShots[index].y); 
        ++index;
    } 
}
```

windows prudocer

```
switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        OnPaint(hdc, hWnd, 1);
        if(iRegularShots==0)
        {
            fRegularShot(hdc, hWnd);
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        iRegularShots=0;
        pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
        pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam); 
        pRegularShots.push_back(pt); 
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false); 
        return 0;
        break; 
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            iRegularShots=1;
            break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you definitely seeing 101 calls to WM_LBUTTONDOWN, or just 101 elements in the vector?

Comment: Do you have a for(int i; i < 100; ++i) {} loop somewhere that's doing something unintended to the vector?

Comment: Can you post your entire window procedure?

Comment: now i have while loop you can see it in my post i just edit it

Comment: i posted it you can take look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg it was my fault i set the vetor to 100 elemnts sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any reason why you would normally get a lot of WM_LBUTTONDOWN events when you press the button once.

Perhaps your previous `case` section (that handles some other message) is missing a `break`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's this code that's generating the 101 entries in the vector - the preceding `case` (if there is one) isn't missing a `break;` is it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you return from the window procedure? [WM_LBUTTONDOWN should return 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607(VS.85).aspx) to indicate the message was handled (if you don't, you'll continue to receive the message until it's handled).